# How should layout and drawable folders be separated properly?

Tags: android, android-layout, drawable

I'm trying to make application run on each device and I come to a problem of making layouts and drawable folders. So, as I'm understanding ratio dpi is following - mdi:hdpi:xhdpi:xxhdpi - 1:1.5:2:3. DPI stands for dots per inch and this dots are actually presenting "DP" as density pixels which we put into XML attribute like: `android:layout_width="150dp"`. (Please, correct me if I'm mistaking)

Problem occurs that some devices can have let's say 240x320 with xhdpi and there can be device 720x1280 also with xhdpi. Even if i would make separated pictures with already mentioned ratio, I would still need to make separated layouts in which:

layout-small would have something like this for ImageView:

```
<ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/slikaPitanja"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_below="@+id/sadrzajTekstualnogPitanja"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:contentDescription="Country flag" />
```

and layout-large where I would have the same code for `ImageView` except I would have these lines:

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

(Actually I could have layouts separated with sw_ _ _dp format).
 Is that right to do it like this? Am I missing point somewhere? Something tells me that it's never good to manually determine dps in width and height as I would for layout-small.

Answer (score 0):

Try to NOT use static dpi for your layout, Instead use "wrap_content , fill-parent and gravity". this will make your layout to spread dynamically depending on the screen size

Comment: The thing is that picture which is for devices with 240x320 is too big if they have hdpi because that ratio is not enough and on 780x1024 picture is too small.